# Difficulties with Forestplot in R

Tags: r

I want to create a forestplot with a rather large amount of studies.

1. When I use the following code with the exemplary dataset, it isn't readable. I want to fit the whole graph onto a A4 Page of a pdf. How can I tell R to fit the graph onto the whole page or how can I make the distance between the rows bigger? I've got much space left on my page.
2. Why are there grey triangles behind my effect sizes? How can I remove those?

```
mlabfun <- function(text, res) {
  list(bquote(paste(.(text),
                    " (Q = ", .(formatC(res$QE, digits=2, format="f")),
                    ", df = ", .(res$k - res$p),
                    ", p ", .(metafor:::.pval(res$QEp, digits=2, showeq=TRUE, sep=" ")), "; ",
                    I^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$I2, digits=1, format="f")), "%, ",
                    tau^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$tau2, digits=2, format="f")), ")")))}


library(metafor)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ind_sample n cond ESxy yi vi
A&B(2019) 40 A 0.1900000 0.19233717 0.0051282051
A&B(2020) 23 A 0.2857738 0.29395814 0.0037453184
D&F(2019) 15 B 0.1800000 0.18198269 0.0108695652
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
A&D(2020) 67 C 0.0200000 0.02000267 0.0024449878
A&U(2019) 90 C 0.1600000 0.16138670 0.0049019608
A&G(2019) 93 C 0.1800000 0.18198269 0.0096153846
A&B(2019) 94 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2016) 33 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2017) 35 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2018) 67 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2019) 12 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2020) 89 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2021) 55 A 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2022) 67 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2023) 32 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2024) 23 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2025) 56 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2026) 23 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2027) 22 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2028) 59 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2028) 69 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2028) 49 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
A&B(2028) 39 C 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0062893082
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
L&U(2020) 29 B 0.1300000 0.13073985 0.0063694268
E&G(2019) 89 B 0.2600000 0.26610841 0.0062111801
H&H(1997) 88 B 0.2300000 0.23418947 0.0084745763
H&U(2020) 12 B 0.2100000 0.21317135 0.0062893082
J&K(2011) 12 B 0.0600000 0.06007216 0.0090909091
L&L(2002) 13 B 0.1200000 0.12058103 0.0006381621
")  


mod_sample_design <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~factor(cond)-1, data = df)

forest(mod_sample_design, at=log(c(0.5, 1,2)), atransf=transf.ztor,
       showweights=TRUE,
       lineheight=unit(2,'cm'),
       slab=df$ind_sample,
       ilab=df$n,
       ilab.xpos=-1, cex=0.4, ylim=c(-1, 104),
       order=df$cond, rows=c(3:10,16:81,86:99),
       mlab=mlabfun("RE Model for All Studies", mod_sample_design),
       psize=1, header="Author(s) and Year")
```

Thank you all so much, that would help me out a lot!

All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to adjust some forest() arguments as for examples :

- you can play with the `alim` et `xlim` arguments to reduce the size
- add `addfit=FALSE` to remove diamons intervals
- to fit to an A4 page, use the dev.print function

The code I used to produce the following pdf :

```
forest(mod_sample_design, atransf=transf.ztor,addfit=FALSE,
       showweights=TRUE,
       lineheight=unit(2,'cm'),
       slab=df$ind_sample,
       ilab=df$n,
       ilab.xpos=-1, cex=0.6,
       order=df$cond, rows=c(3:10,16:81,86:99),
       mlab=mlabfun("RE Model for All Studies", mod_sample_design),
       psize=1, header="Author(s) and Year",alim=c(-0.2,0.45),xlim=c(-0.3,0.65))
dev.print(pdf, file="Forestplot.pdf" ,onefile=T,paper='A4', width = 21/2.54, height = 29.7/2.54)
```

You can adjust other arguments to fit what you need : https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html

[image]