# Forest plot (metafor) with 90 effect sizes: how to make text readable and adjust row spacing

Tags: r, plot, metafor

I am working on a forest plot with the metafor package. With the help of (http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups) and several forum entries I wrote a code but unfortunately the letters are blurry. I tried making the plot bigger with windows () which did help a bit but still it is not ready for putting in a paper.
It looked like this:[also blurry with zooming in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9rYv.jpg)
When I used only a subset of effect sizes for the subgroup analysis the forest plot the text was better readable but only until about 15 effect sizes). And because the row spacing is so narrow I can´t even think about putting summary polygons for subgroups in between.

This was the code I used for my data (90 effect sizes in multilevel model):

```
forest(Model1,
       slab= data$Author, #labeled by author
      # cex=0.75,   #only made the text bigger but did not change the row distance, so the text overlapped
       ylim=c(-1, 100),
      header="Author(s) and Year")
```

There were a lot of extra arguments in examples of forest plots I saw online but I am not sure of their meaning in forest plot.
Does someone know how to solve this spacing problem or what arguments I need to add to the code e.g. to broaden the space between the rows? Is there a “guide” for working with forest?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you have a look at my answer here ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469695/difficulties-with-forestplot-in-r/68471023#68471023

Answer (score 1):

Blurriness has nothing to do with the `forest()` function - it's a matter of how you are saving the plot. You should use functions like `png()` with a high enough resolution. Or use `pdf()` where you can zoom in to your heart's content without ever seeing any blurriness.

As for a "guide", I would suggest reading the documentation first:

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html
https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.default.html

Then you will start to understand what the arguments do.